# Force multiple pipelines to output their results in order

Tags: c, bash, pipe, fork

I'm working on a C program which mimics the $bash terminal.

Part of the project is allowing for functionality with pipes. I have a pipeline built which executes multiple commands connected by a "|" character.

This works perfectly with a single line of commands, for example: `"ls | sort -r"` will return a reversed list of everything in the directory.

However, I get problems when running a script with multiple commands. For example:

```
cat /etc/passwd | sort | sed s/:.*//
echo -----
cat /etc/passwd | sort | sed s/:.*// | grep $(whoami)
echo -----
cat /etc/passwd | sort | grep s | sed s/:.*// | tail -n 3 | head -n 2
```

The above commands will execute properly, but not in the correct order. Since each pipeline is on its own fork, I seems that they are racing each other to completion. I would like the pipelines to run in parallel, but output the results in the proper order.

How can I force them to do this? The relevant code is posted below:

```
void execute_pipeline(struct command_line *cmds, int num_cmds){
int numPipes = (num_cmds - 1);

int fd[numPipes][2];

//Laying pipes
for(int i = 0; i<numPipes; i++){
    if(pipe(fd[i]) == -1){
        perror("pipe");
        return;
    }
}

//Child processes
for(int i = 0; i < numPipes; i++){

    pid_t pid = fork();
    if(pid < 0){
        perror("pid");
        return;
    }

    if (pid == 0) {
        for(int pipe = 0; pipe < numPipes; pipe++){
            for(int connection = 0; connection < 2; connection++){
                if(!((pipe == i && connection == 0) || (pipe == i+1 && connection == 1))){
                    close(fd[pipe][connection]);
                }
            }
        }

        //Final Process
        if(cmds[i+1].stdout_pipe == false){
            //If output file provided, write to file. Otherwise print.
            if(cmds[i+1].stdout_file != NULL){ 
                int fd_out = open(cmds[i+1].stdout_file, O_WRONLY);

                if(fd_out == - 1){
                    perror("Output fd");
                    return;
                }
                dup2(fd_out, STDOUT_FILENO);
            }

            dup2(fd[i][0], STDIN_FILENO);
            if (execvp(cmds[i+1].tokens[0], cmds[i+1].tokens) == -1){
                close(fileno(stdin));
                perror("execvp");
                return;
            }

            close(fd[i][0]);
            // int status;
            // wait(&status);
            // exit(0);      
            return;
        }

        //Middle processes
        dup2(fd[i][0], STDIN_FILENO);
        dup2(fd[i+1][1], STDOUT_FILENO);
        if (execvp(cmds[i+1].tokens[0], cmds[i+1].tokens) == -1){
                close(fileno(stdin));
                perror("execvp");
                return;
            }
            
        close(fd[i][0]);
        close(fd[i+1][1]);
        // exit(0);      

        return;
    }
}

//Parent (first) Process
for(int pipe = 0; pipe < numPipes; pipe++){
    for(int connection = 0; connection < 2; connection++){
        if(!(pipe == 0 && connection == 1)){
            close(fd[pipe][connection]);
        }
    }
}

dup2(fd[0][1], STDOUT_FILENO);
if(execvp(cmds[0].tokens[0], cmds[0].tokens) == -1){
    close(fileno(stdin));
    perror("execvp");
    return;
};
int status;
wait(&status);   

close(fd[0][1]);}
```

Forks each command into a separate pipeline:

```
    pid_t child = fork();
    if(child == -1){
    perror("fork");
    }
    else if (child == 0) {

        execute_pipeline(cmds, cmd_count);
        exit(0);

    }
    else {
        printf("Starting child process., pid = %d\n", child);
        wait(&child);
    }

return 0;
```

Thanks in advance for the advice!

Comment: The 'classic' way to do this is to assign an incrementing 'sequence number' to work requests and then queue up any outputs that arrive out-of-order until all outputs with an earlier sequence number have been handled.

Comment: `wait(&status);` Why do you have any code after `execvp`? You have to `wait` for all the pids.

Comment: I don't understand your question. Are you saying that I should put the wait before the execvp?